# Best Practice - How to extend the DB in a ServiceStack.OrmLite .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5, ormlite-servicestack

I recently took a .Net project over which exposes `DAOs` from a Microsoft SQL Database via ServiceStack REST API. The server runs on IIS 7.5

In the `AppHost.Configure` the complete database schema is created like so...

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(DI.DefaultConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
        using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            if (!db.TableExists(db.GetTableName<SomeSpecificDAO>())) //Create table if not exists
            {
                db.CreateTable<SomeSpecificDAO>();
                db.Insert(new SomeSpecificDAO { Data = 0, AnotherData = "", AnSoOne =  });
            }

        /// alot more tables follow....
        }
```

When I now want to extend a `DAO` (and therefore add a new column to a table for example) I would do this in Visual Studio, test it, and if it works I would remotely add the column via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on the live test server since I do not want to loose any data in the database. This is not very fast when having only one column to add, and it can be very cumbersome if there are more tables/columns added or f.e. the datatype of cells is changed.

What is the best practise in updating the database in Visual studio and on the test system? Is it even possible to have a "Code First approach" where I only extend the `DAO` and then update the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [existing thread in the ServiceStack Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/any-recommendations-for-maintaining-database-schemas/3304) that explains different strategies for handling db schema changes.

Comment: I think DbUp was the one I was looking for. As far as I understood, this would also mean that I use DbUp also for the db schema setup, which I described in the question so that I only have migration scripts which are deployed when I "publish" the app on the server.